# How to deal with json object using type script

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

This is my normal dummy data by '.js'
There is an array and export it.

```
const students = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Sean Grey',
    age: 24
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Sllllean Grey',
    age: 224
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Seansdajfklajs Grey',
    age: 2114
  }
];

export default students;
```

I want to export this dummy data checking typescript.
So I'm thinking use 'class' or 'interface'.
But I don't know the guide for this example.
Could you recommend some advice for me?

Comment: That is an array of objects and has nothing to do with JSON which is a string data format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a way to declare an object structure and fields, which is what [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) is for.

Example:

```
interface Student {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

Usage:

```
const students: Student[] = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Sean Grey',
    age: 24
}];
```